# guardar mas de un valor en un elemento (item) del local storage

Tags: javascript, angular

tengo un proyecto con frontend en angular y estoy tratado de hacer un añadir a favoritos sin necesidad de tener cuenta ni nada almacenandolo en el localstorage.

El código captura un evento clik en un anuncio recogiendo el id del anuncio, luego busca en la api todos los datos del anuncio y los guarda en localstorage generando un array (ja que puedes tener mas de un anuncio en favoritos)
Pues bien hasta aqui lo he podido solucionar bien, El problema es que cuando ya tienes un anuncio en favoritos almacenado en el localstorage y pulsas al botón para agregar otro, se borra el antiguo y se sobrescribe el nuevo. de este modo todo el rato solo me deja almacenar un elemento. haber si alguien puede ayudarme.
Os dejo el código de la función gracias.

```html
  carFav(id){
      //recogo los daots del anuncio
      this._CarService.getCarDetail(id).subscribe(
        response => {
          if(response.status == 'success'){
            //genero el array
            var saveLocal = new Array();
            saveLocal[0] = response.Car;
            //guardo en el local storage
            localStorage.setItem('carFav', JSON.stringify(saveLocal));
          }else{
            console.log(<any>error);
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: saveLocal[0] aquí esta el problema. Para ir almacenando utiliza el metodo push.

Comment: @EugeniBejan y como ultilizo aquí el método push?

Comment: Estoy escribiendo una respuesta. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente siempre estas guardado el dato en la misma posición que es cero en este caso.

Lo otro es que no veo en ninguna parte del código que recojas los valores anteriores para así guardarlos también.

Dicho esto aquí va un ejemplo:

```
//Imaginate que el usuario añadió a favorito estos coches
let carListFav = [
    {name:'car1', id:1},
    {name:'car2', id:2}
]

//Miramos si ya hemos guardado algo anteriormente.
let recoveredData = localStorage.getItem('car')
if(recoveredData == null){
    //No tenemos nada guardado, por lo cual vamos a guardar el carListFav
  localStorage.setItem('car', JSON.stringify(carListFav))
} else {
    //Tenemos algo, por lo cual vamos a añadir un nuevo coche
  let data = JSON.parse(recoveredData)
  let newCar = {name:'car3', id:3}
  //Asegurate que lo que guardes es realmente un array.
  data.push(newCar)
  localStorage.setItem('car', JSON.stringify(data))
}

//Check si se guardo bien
console.log(localStorage.getItem('car'))
```

Espero que te sirva de ejemplo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. La primera vez donde almacena el primer array carListFav perfecto pero luego al pulsar la segunda vez donde tendria que almacenar el 3 junto a los otros 2 me sale un error en la consola de core.js:7187 ERROR ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Fallo mio, ya esta arreglado.